# How can I add a new row to CSV file in pure JS

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm currently working on a project. I created a CSV file and I want to append data in it. I've been searching for hours and all I found was with Node.js. But I want to do it with pure JS. Thanks in advance.

Good Day

Comment: you must be running your code somewhere. is it a browser or other javascript runtime? do you want to save the file to disk?

Comment: you can try reading csv into array, append data and create new csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot append data in a file using javascript it is because javascript is a client/browser-based language you have to use some kind of server-side language to do that.

You have options like:

- Node
- PHP

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how Node.js is not JavaScript?

Comment: You run javascript code on in node.js but node is specifically built to interact with I/O operations which alone javascript can not do.

Before node we were only allowed to run javascript in browser from where we cannot access any file or database outside from the browser. we needed another server supported language to do those tasks. Then javascript devs came together and solved this problem by implementing supported helper libraries to make javascript work out side of the browser which means now those libraries can help javascript run on server and those libraries are called node.js